# PHP display strings starting with a letter and after

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization

I'm dealing with a filtering system is currently making in PHP and I've hit a brick wall whilst trying to make a dictory to users.

I fetch a list of users from the database ordered by the last name which gives us a theoretical list like this :

```
[
  {
    "first name" : "Bob",
    "Last name"  : "Éthier"
  },
  {
    "first name" : "Paul",
    "Last name"  : "Foo"
  },
  {
    "first name" : "Alice",
    "Last name"  : "Smith"
  },
]
```

Now issues arrive when I'm trying to make a list of said users starting at a certain alphabet letter , "A,B,C,..."

If I were to do something such as

```
if(strtoupper(substr($arr["Last name"], 0, 1)) >= $filterLetter)
   // Add account to display list to eventually show on page
```

What I would like to happen is that when I select the letter "F" as a filter, my list shows F and above, so basically it would start off with every other person with the letter F and eventually continue and also display Smith and so on.

What currently happens is that if the letter filter I select is above some accented character, the string compares part of the program bugs out and considers it good anyway and displays it.

Currently when I select F as my "start index", Bob Éthier shows even though it shouldn't and I'm honestly not sure why that happens. It seems to happen with every accented letter not only É.

Is there something I'm missing because I really feel like "É" > F should be false but in my case it's true.

Edit: My database system is:**MySql** and my charset is **latin1** and collation is **latin1_swedish_ci** ( This might very well could be part of the issue), the characters do show properly on the page.

Comment: Probably multibyte, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php... and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php

Comment: Have you used UTF-8 collation in your MySQL table?

Comment: @RaviManiyar There's nothing about mysql here.

Comment: @user3783243 - it is, check the second line stated by OP.

Comment: @RaviManiyar The OP gets the content outputted on the page correctly so presumably it is correct. Also `mysql` isn't the only `database`.

Comment: Although he could reduce his return results through a sql query... he is currently reducing the results with php on the whole list returned from the db. So no need to argue either way ;) but this might prove easier in the sql... as 'hacking out accent' characters is really a crap way to go about it.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am doing it in PHP as a way to avoid constantly making calls to the database as the amount of accounts I'm dealing with are well within the 1000s.I currently load the list when a user enters the directory page and then filter through a cached array of what the query fetched to avoid fetching everytime someone makes something as simple as a letter change. Granted that might not be the most efficient way to go about it , I'm really not certain on that. I figured it would be faster ... :/

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, if you were hitting the db everytime (grabbing all), it would be just as bad as using sql to filter the list. But if you are caching the results in some manner to reduce the pull load, then sifting through it in php is the plan. You could even pre-sift every group and stuff it all into a json variable for javascript to visually show/hide to completely avoid more hits... but that is more involved and first things first is getting the 'groups' right by first char of last name ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use iconv to remove the diacritics. Make sure to set the locale properly or iconv can return unexpected characters. The following should work:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
$char = mb_substr($arr["Last name"], 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
$char = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$char);
```

Then use $char to compare against your index.

**Edit**: substr doesn't work with accented characters, using mb_substr and passing UTF-8 as encoding fixes the issue.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
$char = substr("Éthier", 0, 1);
$char = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$char);
var_dump($char);
` -- this prints `bool(false)`.

Comment: Stripping accents is probably a bad plan as in some languages they affect ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below-given function to convert your accented strings to normal strings and then continue with your necessary checks.

```
function removeAccents($str) {
  $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ', 'Ά', 'ά', 'Έ', 'έ', 'Ό', 'ό', 'Ώ', 'ώ', 'Ί', 'ί', 'ϊ', 'ΐ', 'Ύ', 'ύ', 'ϋ', 'ΰ', 'Ή', 'ή');
  $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o', 'Α', 'α', 'Ε', 'ε', 'Ο', 'ο', 'Ω', 'ω', 'Ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'Υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'Η', 'η');
  return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}
```

`$str` is your accented string and the result that the function will return will be an acceptable string stored in `$normalString`

```
$str = 'Chloé'
$normalString = removeAccents($str);
```

This way you shouldn't have an issue at all with accented characters.

Comment: In some languages "A" and "Å" are not the same thing, and "Æ" and "AE" are most certainly not. There's also letters like "þ" and "ð" which aren't accents at all.

Comment: @tadman I completely agree. This function is just to convert and help someone filter easily without any issues. I **haven't** mentioned anywhere to convert and save the converted strings.

Comment: I'm not saying that either, I'm saying that collation issues are way more complicated than this trivial bit of code implies.